# Correct syntax for curl command for conceptualSearch Watson API

Tags: curl, ibm-watson, concept-insights

I have setup a private corpus called devoxx_corpus1. I can successfully run :

```
curl -u "username":"password" -G -d "ids=[\"/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Java_(programming_language)\"]" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/eve6tionsto1/devoxx_corpus1/conceptual_search"
```

But not able to run the same command after adding `document_fields={\"user_fields\":1}`  which is very important to add while doing conceptualSearch in my project.

Can you please give me the correct syntax to run the curl command with the above concept and `document_fields`.

Answer (score 2):

I added `-d 'document_fields={"user_fields":1}'` to the command line, and it seems to work.

For example, this curl invocation worked for me in using the public TEDTalks corpus:

> curl -u username:password -G -d 'ids=["/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Java_(programming_language)"]' -d 'document_fields={"user_fields":1}' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/public/TEDTalks/conceptual_search"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The command works ! . An additional question, can I ignore results returned from wikipedia graph, because I am interested in results from my corpus only.